# Machine learning algorithms in scikit-learn normalized value?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

First to use machine learning algorithm of scikit-learn module for image set, how can i prepare features images? 
May i normalize values with Standard deviation (i.e. in Nearest Neigbour or cluster algorithms)?
Or may i linearly scale with (featureValue-min) / (max -min) as i saw here: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/talks/mlss_kyoto.pdf for svm.

Comment: I would recommend rephrasing your question as "what are the typical pre-processing steps that must be performed on data for machine learning". Using Scikit-learn or any other library does not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Please read this: ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_std
If your features are drawn from a Gaussian distribution, then you standardize with the SD and mean. Otherwise, you would just normalize/rescale to bring them to a range of 0-1. A lot of pre-processing tends to be dependent on data and the technique chosen. Find what suits your data and technique best.

Answer (score 0):

Not all the algorithms call for a normalized input vector, such as Random forest algorithm. However if your choice of algorithm calls for normalization say SVM then normalize it use the normalizers available in Sklearn from preprocessing module and the transform your data to normalized data before fitting it. Also, if you are trying to classify images then look into PCA(principle component analysis) in sklearn this helps you to use selected feature for processing and provides better performance and results